Unexpected Behavior After Visual Studio and NuGet Update - part of button on stop to send event
I recently updated Visual Studio and NuGet on my development machine and application.
After the update, I encountered an issue with my Android application.
Some buttons are no longer functioning as expected.

Certain buttons are no longer triggering the intended event when clicked.
Other buttons are still sending events, but they are routed to the wrong location within the application.

No Code Changes

Did you try to test on different devices? In addition, you can try to delete the bin and obj folder and then clean and rebuid it.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT sure. i try test it on different machine, on different simulator, on 2 different android devices. shift+delete bin folder - recompile - and same results.
no possible that its only on my devices. i saw many issues with same poroblem from 2022

Could you please post some relevant code to help us reproduce this question? What the .NET version do you use?

@LiqunShen-MSFT this is the point - the code is nothing special. its just 3 button in grid and two of them are not send the event to the model-view. the one button that send event are same as the other two. when i change to run it on windows its work ok - the problem is only on android

That's weird. Does it happen if you create a new default project and use the relevant code?
